# How could I pass a variable into an Ionic datetime input property?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I would like to pass a variable, `someVar`, into the `max` attribute (input property) of an Ionic 2 (and Angular 2) DateTime component. It seems to only accept a hard-coded string, e.g. `max="2017-08-31"`.

**HTML**

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" max="someVar" [(ngModel)]="toDate"></ion-datetime>
```

**JavaScript**

```
export class myPage {

  public someVar: string = ''; // linked to another user input

  constructor() {}

}
```

Comment: change `max="someVar"` and  `public someVar: string = '';`

Answer (score 1):

i assume that's angular 2? you could pass it as a string, for example:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" max="some-var" [(ngModel)]="'fromDate'"></ion-datetime>
```

notice the quotes (**'**)

Comment: Yes, Angular 2. The problem is with the `max` attribute, which is an input for the DateTime component. I tried passing it a string, for example: `max="'some-var'"` but that doesn't work.

Comment: been trivial, but if the example is like in the code, the naming convention might be problematic (should use someVar in the html instead of some-var)

Comment: The code is not like the example but well spotted, I thought it looked wrong!

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to pass a variable to the max property, passing today's date to `ngModel` ensures that the maximum date available for that field is 31 December of the current year.

Capping the "To" date at today would have been nice but it is not essential.

Comment: To pass variable to max property, do this ` max="{{ this.maxDate }}" ` where of course, maxDate is declared in the .ts file

Answer (score 0):

To pass variable to max property, pass it in {{ }} like this

```html
<ion-datetime #picker pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY" min="2018" max="{{ this.todayDate }}"></ion-datetime>
```

where of course, maxDate is declared in the .ts file